# returns to login screen when backing out for the first time, Kotlin + Android Studio + Firebase

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication

I just finished my login, but when the user logs in for the first time and goes back to the login screen. I don't know why but when you open the app for the second time now if everything goes well (you go back and the app closes), I would like to know why that first time it goes back to the login screen.
This is my code:

```
        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        if (user != null) {
            val intent = Intent(this, home::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        }
```

Comment: You're setting the _Intent_ tag **after** starting a new _Activity_ which makes no effect. Set the flag before starting the _Activity_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `.setflag` before using the `intent`.
I would also use the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`-flag - try this:

```
        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        if (user != null) {
            val intent = Intent(this, home::class.java)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
```